# Wordpress: shortcode not executing within html element's attribute

Tags: wordpress

My example shortcodes are [abc-href] and [abc-title]
I am trying like this:

```
<a href="[abc-href]" title="[abc-title]">Link text here</a>
```

It is not being executed, can anyone reply why it is? And how I can execute this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Shortcodes are not allowed in html attributes, shortcodes are not programing language, they are place holders to proper html content.

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="<?php echo do_shortcode('[abc-href]');?>" title="<?php echo do_shortcode('[abc-title]');?>">Link text here</a>
```

Try this.

Comment: ok. then first of all check it in template. then paste same in editor

Comment: Your code is working in template, my concern is related to work this in editor.

Comment: to do this i want to check your code. my skype: harryr891